# Method type ~ symbol

Tags: c#

Question: What does this mean and for what use would one implement this:

```
public class Parameter : Variable
{
    public Parameter(NDArrayView value);

    ~Parameter();

    public override void Dispose();
}
```

Of course, the question is specifically targeting this Method Constructor:

```
~Parameter();
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is a finalizer. What use is it? In practical terms, none at all. It is incredibly rare to need to write a finalizer in 2019.

Comment: See [Finalizers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ~ used in above code serves purpose of destructor. Like how
>   constructor is used to initialize some values or object, destructor is
>   used for exactly opposite purpose. It has same name as class like
>   constructor, but it starts with ~ operator.

Answer (score 0):

The ~ symbol can be use for :

1/. [Finaliser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors) declaration:

```
class Car
{
    ~Car()  // finalizer
    {
        // cleanup statements...
    }
}
```

2/. [Bitwise complement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#bitwise-complement-operator-), produces a bitwise complement of its operand by reversing each bit.